# Why does this assembly code throw a seg fault?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86, nasm

The book *Assembly Language Step by Step* provides the following code as a sandbox:

```
section .data
section .text

global _start                

_start:

    nop
    //insert sandbox code here
    nop
```

Any example that I include in the space for sandbox is creating a segmentation fault. For example, adding this code:

```
mov ax, 067FEh
mov bx, ax
mov cl, bh
mov ch, bl
```

Then compiling with:

```
nasm -f macho sandbox.asm
ld -o sandbox -e _start sandbox.o
```

creates a seg fault when I run it on my OS/X. Is there a way to get more information about what's causing the segmentation fault?

Comment: Running it under a debugger would be a good start. In this case cause of the crash is probably because after executing the last NOP instruction in your program, the CPU continues to execute what instructions happen to be in memory following it.

Comment: if I run it in a debugger it terminates automatically with a seg fault.

Comment: Ideally you would hope that the behaviour of your program wouldn't change when run under a debugger. It should at least tell you where your program crashed and what instruction caused the crash.

Comment: `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002002 in ?? ()` is there a way to protect/fench the program from any instructions that happen to be in memory following it?

Comment: If that is the sum total of your code, you are crashing because you're running past the end of your code. The random data hanging out there is interpreted as actual code, resulting in a segfault as soon as it tries to read or write memory out of your memory area.

Comment: @DavidHoelzer that is the sum total of the code. As stated in the OP, it was provided as a sandbox by the book to test small snippets of code (that go between the two `nop`). Can you provide an answer that shows how to alter the code so it doesn't seg fault?

Comment: Sure.  Stick a `ret` on the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that you have created a program that runs past the end of the code that you have written.

When your program executes, the loader will end up issuing a `jmp` to your `_start`. Your code then runs, but you do not have anything to return to the OS at the end, so it will simply continue running, executing whatever bytes happen to be in RAM after your code.

The simplest fix would be to properly exit the code. For example:

```
mov eax, 0x1              ; system call number for exit
sub esp, 4                ; OS X system calls needs "extra space" on stack
int 0x80
```

Since you are not generating any actual output, you would need to step through with a debugger to see what's going on.  After compiling you could use `lldb` to step through.

```
lldb ./sandbox
image dump sections
```

Make note of the address listed that is of type `code` for your executable (not dyld). It will likely be 0x0000000000001fe6.  Continuing within lldb:

```
b s -a 0x0000000000001fe6
run
register read
step
register read
step
register read
```

At this point you should be past the NOPs and see things changing in registers.  Have fun!

Comment: I added a `ret` after the move instructions. Same result. I moved the `ret` to after the final `nop` and same result.

Comment: My apologies.  I had my head in the old 16/32 bit real mode world for a minute. This should solve it for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the extra information (I didn't know about lldb tool, I was using gdb). The address listed for type code is `0x0000000000001fe9`. When I run `b s -a 0x0000000000001fe9` it gives me an `unable to resolve breakpoint to any actual locations` warning.  After `run` it exists with status = 1 and then `register read` says `error invalid thread`

Comment: Double check the address marked as code.. make sure you didn't grab a data address instead.

Comment: Execution begins at the entry point from a jump, but the jump isn't a `call`.  There's no return address on the stack.  (At least, not in Linux.  I doubt OS X literally runs a `call` in user-space either.)  It's more likely an `iret` or maybe a `sysret`.  To avoid over-complicating your answer, I'd suggest saying "the loader jumps to your `_start`", which gives the impression of running a `jmp` instruction.  That mental model is fine for writing correct user-space code.

Comment: True, Peter.  Thanks.